# Why is django not showing the content what I declare in template?

Tags: django

I have the following in the templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rango</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Rango says...</h1>
    hello world! <strong>foo</strong><br />
    <a href="/rango/about/">About</a><br />
</body>
```

How ever, the output is the following (page source)

```
<Text Node: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 '>
```

What could be the reason?

EDIT:

Here is my view code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader



# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')

    return HttpResponse(template)
```

Comment: How do you render your template? Give us the view-code.

Comment: I have updated the description- the view is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) the template in the view.
Try the [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) shortcut.
Otherwise show us the view code.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was that I had to render the template. thx